# Change Color Of A Monotone Icon To Another Color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, icon, color-conversion

Basically, I'm a programmer and I'm pretty new to graphics design, and I don't have much knowledge of the keywords used by the graphic design community. That's why I'm facing problem in googling this out. I've an image like this:-

[image]

As we can see that there is only one color in it. How can I convert this icon into a red color, white color, or a custom HEX or RGA colored icon? As it is only one color and have a transparent background so I believe that this is pretty easy. But I don't know how.

Basically, I'm a GIMP user. If you can tell me this in GIMP then that would be great. However, if you can tell me this in Adobe Photoshop then I can search for similar technique in GMIP.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Gimp use the *Colors -> Colorize* tool:

[image]

We can then adjust the color with the *Hue* slider, the saturation with the *Saturation* slieder, the brightness with the *Lightness* slider to desired values. We can save or import our preset for use in a different icon file.

A much better approach from a programmers view would be however to not have this icon as a bitmap file but a vector format such as .SVG. An .SVG file is entirely written with XML so that colors could easily be assigned programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

For Photoshop, easiest way is to create a hue/saturation adjustment layer (circular icon at the bottom of the layers panel).

In the hue/saturation panel, click 'colorize' and adjust the color slider to whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Open the icon in Adobe photoshop and go to image mode greyscale, then go again to image mode duotone, from the menu bar choose monotone and click on the square of colors to choose which color you want then save it back as GIF or PNG to preserve the transparent Background

BEST